# Did Sugreeva have a child?

Tags: ramayana, sugriva

Did Sugreeva have a son (or a daughter perhaps)? If so what is his name? I have heard that he had a son but I am not sure about the name.

Answer (score 5):

Sugriva had no offspring.  This can be understood from the words of Sri Hanuman.

Sugriva sends 1 troop of vanaras for searching Sita in Southern side under the leadership of Angada, son of Vali. He put a general condition that the vanara troops  should come back within a month, otherwise they face death punishment.

The vanaras under the leadership of Angada while searching for Sita enters a black cave and got struck inside the cave.  Unknown to them much time had elapsed and the After getting out of black cave they found that the 1 month deadline fixed by Sugriva had elapsed.

Afraid of facing Sugriva, Angada says he will not return to Kishkinda.  It was then Sri Hanuman says Sugriva will install Angada as the king of Vanaras, as Sugriva had no progeny.

> प्रिय कामः च ते मातुः तत् अर्थम् च अस्य जीवितम् |
>
> तस्य अपत्यम् च न अस्ति अन्यत् तस्मात् अंगद गम्यताम् || ([Kishkinda
>   Kanda 54th Sarga 22nd sloka](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga54/kishkindha_54_frame.htm))
>
> "He is your mother's wellwisher, the strife of Sugreeva's life is for
>   her only, more so, **there is no other posterity to him than you**. Oh,
>   Angada, therefore go back to Kishkindha, rather than deflecting,
>   deviating and deserting your own kingdom.

Comment: Some folklore says Dadhibala was Sugriva's son who killed Narantaka in Raama-Raavana war..